# How to generate XML documentation file in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core

I am interested how can I create `XML documentation file` in VS2015 with ASP.NET MVC6 project? In older project types there was a checkbox called `XML documentation file`  when you do right click on `Properties -> Build`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special, it generates it by default and puts it inside the NuGet package for you.

Refer to [here](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/f1b13799a4e165147827ebecb8dff00f6f48e677/src/Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn/RoslynProjectReference.cs#L237-L244) if you want to see where exactly this happens.

Comment: Did we just post the answers at the same time? :)

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci I have beaten you by 1 min :D

Comment: Ok, then your answer stays. I'll remove mine which said "XML documentation should be emitted by default. The documentation should be in `<assembly name>.xml` in the same folder as the output. The code is [here](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/32358ec9b8970070ff77cbc5beef28c13e3ab09b/src/Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn/RoslynProjectReference.cs#L154-L156)

Comment: So is there a way that I can get the XML path while I am running the application on IIS Express?

Comment: When I do publish and if I don't select `Precompile during publishing` I will not get that .xml file. Same thing when I do `build`, if I do not select `Produce outputs on build` I will not get that XML. I would like to access that file from the code and use it for Swashbuckle.

Comment: Yes, you have to select "Produce outpus on build" without that flag is like running "dnu build" which only compiles (fast!) but doesn't create packages or assemblies.